# Java 2 Dimensional Arrays to 3D Points (Objects) gives out Null pointer exception error.

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, nullpointerexception

The goal of my program (2 Classes) is to use objects by obtaining input from the main class, and passing it on for such suggested values. The user is asked for a range of the x,y,z coordinates and the number of coordinates he wishes to generate. However, when I run the program I proceed to get this error :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DataPoints.getArray(DataPoints.java:31)
    at Client.main(Client.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Similar to my last question, it appeared as the same error, however last time it was a problem with not using static methods. This time it seems completely different, as when trying to write to a file (The values of X,Y,Z) the file remains empty as well.

I have tried checking the values of the given user input, in seeing that if the input is registered and simply not set to 0. Furthermore, I have made an attempt in removing the print writer class, to no avail. While making the getArray method within the setter of the array, worked logically (The code runs) but proceeds with the same null exception error. Any input would be more than appreciated!

Client Class

```
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    DataPoints c = new DataPoints();
    double dataArray [] [] = new double[3] [10000] ; 
    double range;
    int numPoints;
    String input;

    System.out.println("Please enter a range for (X,Y,Z) , As each value is approached from \nPostive infinity and Negative infinity");
    System.out.println("In other words a true value is used, for instance entering '100' would be of the range '100' --> '-100'");
    input = myInput.readLine(); 
    range = Double.parseDouble(input);
    c.setRange(range);

    System.out.println("Now please enter the amount you want to generate (NumPoints variable)");
    input = myInput.readLine();
    numPoints = Integer.parseInt(input);
    c.setNumPoints(numPoints);
    c.setArray(dataArray);

    // d = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 z^2) 
   System.out.println(c.getArray());
  }
}
```

Object Class

```
import java.io.*;

public class DataPoints {

  BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));  // allow input
  private double myArray[][]; 
  private int myNumPoints;
  private double myRange;
  private int i;
  public DataPoints() {

  }

  public void writeData (double myArray[][]) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter printWriter = (new PrintWriter ("file.txt"));
    printWriter.println("The numbers in notation --> (X,Y,Z) are as follows (" + myArray[0][i] + ") (" + myArray[1][i] + ") (" + myArray[2][i] + ")");
  printWriter.close();

  }

  public void setArray (double [][] myArray) {
    for (i = 0; i < myNumPoints; i++ ) {
      myArray[0][i] =  2* (double)(Math.random () * myRange) - myRange; //first position of array ...
      myArray[1][i] =  2* (double)(Math.random () * myRange) - myRange; // second position ofarray..
      myArray[2][i] =  2* (double)(Math.random () * myRange) - myRange; // third position of array...

    }
  }
  public double getArray() 
  { 
    return myArray[0][i];
  } 

  public void setNumPoints(int NumPoints) {
    myNumPoints = NumPoints;
  }

  public int getNumPoints() {
    return myNumPoints;
  }

  public void setRange(double Range) {
    myRange = Range; 
  }

  public double getRange() {
    return myRange;  
  }
}
```

Comment: If you've dealt with NPE before, then surely you know that the line number is the most important part of the exception message. So surely you know that you should tell us which lines are throwing the NPE.

Comment: Find out what value i has when you call getArray(). Looks like that is what is giving you the exception. Sounds like for some reason the array is longer than you think and has elements that have not been initialized.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Without counting it appears to be the getArray method since the method only has a single line. Looks like whatever element i points to is null at the time the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks @Radiodef. He really should be providing this information for us. I'm kind of surprised that he's making us guess, or making us count, which will likely be incorrect since we don't know if there's a package statement.

Comment: Looks like @Taylor is correct. I was blinded by the assumption the line number mattered and skipped over the important mistake. The array is just null. : )

Answer (score 1):

2 problems:

1. you never initialize DataPoints.myArray
2. DataPoints.setArray's parameter is named myArray, same as DataPoints.myArray so your code in setArray is referring to the parameter not the instance member.

Comment: Yep, that's it. `writeData` does the same thing, also referring to the arg and not the instance member.

Comment: Ya although it's hard to tell if that's intentional, the state management's a bit of a mess.

Comment: Yeah. I don't see any kind of `myArray =` statement though so it is definitely null at the point the method is called. OP, the _other_ methods that reference myArray do not throw exceptions because the references to myArray in those methods refer to the parameter. The _field_ called myArray is always null from the very beginning.

Comment: @Radiodef yup exactly.  The identically-named parameter is "masking" the null set of DataPoints.myArray